# "[[FIRAuth auth] signInWithCredential:credential..." error

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

"Hi, everybody!"

I have implemented Firebase's SignInWithApple authentication as per the sample in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple?hl=ja), but I get an error that the type of argument given to signInWithCredential is different.

How should I handle this?

I am building using Xcode Version 13.3.

Programmatically, it retrieves `FIROAuthCredential* credential = ...`, which is
`[[FIRAuth auth] signInWithCredential:credential ...`,
but since the first argument of `signInWithCredential` must be a `FIRAuthCredential*`.

I think compiler is correct that it will result in a build error, but I do not know how to get the `FIRAuthCredential` pointer variable from `FIROAuthCredeential* credential`.

Please help, if you know.